# How can i replace rows with another record in extjs grid?

Tags: extjs

if i have 5 rows in my grid

```
a 30
b 35
c 47
d 50
f 70
```

how can i replace c 47 with ca 12,cb 14,cc 20 that is,like this

```
a 30
b 35
ca 12
cb 14
cc 20 
d 50
f 70
```

Thanks in advance .... :)

Comment: The specific ExtJS version you use could be of importance here. Do you use 4.1? Also, by 'replacing' do you really mean there's no more `c` row, and now there are 3 new records, or is there something more hierarchy related (so you might want to go back to row `c`?

Comment: hi,i am using 3.2.yes,just replace the c with new 3 records(there's no more c).I don't want to go back to row c.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way to do this is to change the store.

```
var store = grid.getStore();

store.on('load', changeRowC ,this);

var changeRowC = function(){

    //loop on your data of store and insert records ca, cb, cc 

}
```